# Problem with a new version of django and python code

Tags: python, django

I'm stuck with Django here, I have added the code of views.py and urls.py below. I'm getting the following error:

[This is the error im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXTVL.png)

Please look into it and help me if there is any solution to it.
  The error is at the bottom of the image.

```
 views.py 
 from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
 from django.utils import timezone
 from .models import Post, Comment
 from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

 from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                              DetailView,CreateView,
                              UpdateView,DeleteView)

 from django.urls import reverse_lazy
   from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

# Create your views here.
class AboutView(TemplateView):
  template_name = 'blog/about.html'
```

class PostListView(ListView):
      model = Post

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return 
  Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('- 
   published_date')

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


  class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
   login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

   form_class = PostForm

     model = Post


   class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
      login_url = '/login/'
      redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm

     model = Post


  class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin,DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')


  class DraftListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_draft_list.html'

   model = Post

   def get_queryset(self):
       return 
  Post.objects.filter(published_date__isnull=True).order_by('created_date')



   @login_required
    def post_publish(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    post.publish()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=pk)

  @login_required
    def add_comment_to_post(request, pk):
     post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
       if request.method == "POST":
       form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           comment = form.save(commit=False)
           comment.post = post
           comment.save()
           return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'blog/comment_form.html', {'form': form})


    @login_required
     def comment_approve(request, pk): 

     comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
     comment.approve()
     return redirect('post_detail', pk=comment.post.pk)


@login_required
def comment_remove(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    post_pk = comment.post.pk
    comment.delete()
    return redirect('post_detail', pk=post_pk)
***This is urls.py***
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.urls import path, include
 from django.contrib.auth import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout/', views.logout, name='logout', kwargs= 
    {'next_page': '/'}),
    ]
 from django.urls import path
 from . import views


 urlpatterns = [
  path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
  path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
  path('post/<int:pk>', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
  path('post/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
  path('post/<int:pk>/edit/', views.PostUpdateView.as_view(), 
name='post_edit'),
   path('drafts/', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name='post_draft_list'),
   path('post/<int:pk>/remove/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), 
name='post_remove'),
   path('post/<int:pk>/publish/', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
   path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, 
name='add_comment_to_post'),
     path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, 
name='comment_approve'),
   path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.comment_remove, 
  name='comment_remove'),
 ]
```

Please let me know what the mistake is.
The above files are views.py, urls.py for app as well.
Look at the image the error has been mentioned at the bottom.

Comment: Hi, you should try to make your questions as simple as possible. In this case it would really help if you would show the error you get in this question and not in an image posted on another website, and you should think about if you'd need to post views.py and if it would need to include all this code.
In this case, I think your problem is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975657/attributeerror-module-django-contrib-auth-views-has-no-attribute-login and  you should change views.login to views.LoginView.as_view()

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error try this url for django login view:

```
    path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
```