# Openstack Horzion install -> AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm following OpenStack installation guide to install Train.
Trying to install Horizon but stuck in an error when I try to login via dashboard.

My apache2 error log:

```
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678452 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994] ERROR django.request Internal Server Error: /horizon/auth/login/
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678593 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678636 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678681 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     response = get_response(request)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678713 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678744 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678775 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678806 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678837 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py", line 76, in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678869 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678899 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 142, in _wrapped_view
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678930 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678960 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.678991 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.679021 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openstack_auth/views.py", line 120, in login
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.679052 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994]     res = django_auth_views.login(request,
[Mon Mar 09 15:24:34.679085 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 17044:tid 140208455399168] [remote 127.0.0.1:60994] AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'
```

I looked over here and I found a similar error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975657/attributeerror-module-django-contrib-auth-views-has-no-attribute-login/50851643) but I don't know where to find the files that I need to change.

Django version: 2.2.11
Python version: 3.6.9